Windows and Ubuntu are recognized as installed in the same drive
I have 2 SSDs. Let's call the first one C and the second one D.
When I installed Windows first on C and then installed Ubuntu on D, everything went fine.
But I had to reinstall Windows for some reason, so I did.
The problem arose here.
I certainly reinstalled Windows on the C drive (as a clean installation), but in the BIOS, both Windows and Ubuntu are recognized as if they are installed on the same drive, which is D.
Of course, they are installed on different drives.
And after reinstallation, I cannot open D on Windows, and C on Linux. It worked properly before reinstallation.
So I'm confused about why this could happen and wondering if I have to reinstall from the beginning.
For now both OS seem to work fine.

What brand/model system? Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned driived. This will show lots of details of your installs: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Boot-Repair is really only for Linux systems and it either updates or reinstall grub to fix most boot issues.
